# How to use CSS in vue.js apps?

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component

I'm having trouble understanding how exactly I should build sites with CSS. I get that each component has it's own CSS, but should I do this with every component? What if the components are huge with a lot of CSS?

I've looked at some sites that were built with vue.js and they have external CSS files such as a `app.css` file with a ton of internal style blocks.

I'm use to building sites with Sass in it's own `/styles` directory and having compass.app compile those `.scss` files into `.css` files.

Here's an example of a component css block:

```
<style lang="scss">
h1, h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  a {
    color: red;
  }
}
</style>
```

What if that was a thousand+ lines? Would I move that into an external scss file and if so, how? How does this all work?

Thanks.

Comment: if your styling is so long for a single component, perhaps your component could be broken into smaller reusable components?

Comment: If you have a global list of styles like bootstrap or even anything general that you want to use in each component, then make it global and require it in your app.vue or your application entry point, otherwise if each component has it's own unique style, it makes sense to include it in it's own component, also what @Dean said is true

Comment: Okay I understand that. So is it okay for a website to have a hundred style blocks instead of a seperate css file?  I think that's my biggest confusion because I've always had my styles in a seperate files for what I thought was for good reasons and clean code, and smaller html documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you concern is about code separation you can have custom CSS code in a component and add a scoped attribute so the styles you are writing there would only apply to that component:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>

    /* your scoped css rules here will only apply to this component */

</style>
```

Now if you also want to compile the CSS from all of your components and merge them into a single final CSS file that you would link from your main HTML file then you need to add a bundler/compiler such as [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)

You can also take a look at [vue css-loader](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/css-modules.html) to understand how to modularize and compose your CSS rules.